# Just read numbers in line from file

Tags: java

I have a sequence of line in a file named as avar.txt. In file, I try to read a number which is not started with '£' character. To do so, I have wrote below code but, I do not know how to get number in it. Is it possible to directly get number from file instead of my approach, actually my approach not working?

```
£Life                                  <--------------- do not read
£No File Name               Contents  <--------------- do not read

00  life.all                    ... 
£01 life.prt                    ...   <--------------- do not read
03  life.all                    ...
11  life.pl                     ...

£Expectation                           <--------------- do not read
£No File Name               Contents  <--------------- do not read
13  expectation.ops             ...
04  expectation.at              ...
£05 expectation.anil            ...   <--------------- do not read
```

Expected read numbers; 00, 03, 11, 13, 04

Just to note that each number preceeded with tab charater like `<tab(i.e. whitespace)><number>`

My not working code, (I donot know how to extract number from it)

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("avar.txt");
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(file);

for( String tmp = null ; tmp = read.readLine() != null;){
    number.add(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you only want to use the number.If you want to use the rest of the please update your post and i will update the answer.

So only for the numbers, you can do the following:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Avar.txt"));

while(in.hasNextLine){
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(in.nextLine());
    if(lineScanner.hasNextInt()){
        int x = lineScanner.nextInt();
        // do something with x
    }

}
```

This will read you input line by line. For every line, if the line starts with an int ( a line starting with `"£01"` does not start with an int) then that `int` will be stored in the variable `x`. After that you can do w/e. If you want them all you can pass them in an `Array` etc...

**`BufferedReader` Version:**

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Avar.txt"));
String line;
while((line = file.readLine()) != null){
    if(line.charAt(0) >= 48 && line.charAt(0) <= 57 ){
        String number = line.substring(0, 2);
        int x = Integer.valueOf(number);
        //do something with x
    }
}       
file.close();
```

Same logic as the `Scanner` version.

Hope this helps

Comment: in your code, where did you "not read a line started with '£' character" ? Which statement?

Comment: inside the while loop i pass every line into a new `Scanner`. Then my `if` statement checks if that line starts with an `int`.. `if(lineScanner.hasNextInt())`.. As i said a line starting with `£01` does not start with an `int` so it will not go inside the `if` statement and will continue to the next line.

Comment: IF you still having problems let me know.

Comment: For each line, instantiation of Scanner class is actually so ugly. For each time, I will use one time and then left it. For small file, it is okey but for large file, do it arise a performance problem?

Comment: Well first of all you didn't mention in your question that performance is an issue. Second, how big of a file are we talking about? If you are in the 10's of thousands of lines then buffered classes will do better yes.

Comment: If I use buffered class, how to get integer like you did.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("avar.txt");
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(file);

for( String tmp = null ; tmp = read.readLine() != null;){

    String [] strNumArray = tmp.split(" ");

    number.add(strNumArray[0]);
}
```

Something along the lines above could would by splitting your row into parts seperated by a space symbol.

Comment: You could then use the above and see if it is a number by trying to parse it in a try catch statement.

Comment: If its not a number it will error and go onto the next line in the text file

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
File ifile = new File("avar.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(ifile.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
  if (!line.startsWith("£")) {
       ...... Type your code.....//it takes line without "£" sign.
   }
 }
```

if you want just numbers like this.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner("Avar.txt");
while(in.hasNextInt)
{
    int n = in.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: I think your code is not working in case of "<some text>£". I am not guaranteeing that '£' will not occur in the text body. I just said if it is not started with '£' character, read this line. Am I wrong?

Comment: I wonder how do proceed with first recommendation. In other words, how do you extract integers from `line`. _By the way, I am not downvoted you actually I have no enough reputation._

Comment: It depends on your logic and rules. Suppose to every line starts with integer which are without '£' sign. 

        int i = 0;
        String val = "";
        while (line.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            val = val + line.charAt(i);
            i++;
        }

or 

        String val = "";
        for(String s:line.split(" "))
        {
            val =s;
            break;
        }